# How to call a Scala function with short parameter list?

Tags: scala, copy

Suppose I have a Scala class with update method:

```
case class User (id: Integer, name: String, surname: String, address: String) {
    def update (name: String, surname: String, address: String): Unit = {
        copy (name, surname, address)
    }        
}
```

Is it possible with Scala to call update function with one or two parameters and delegate call to copy function? Like this:

```
val user: User = User (1, "name", "surname", "address")
user.update(name: "name") // Here it delegate to call copy (name)
```

Or do I have to copy and paste every update function for each case?

Comment: Is the update method supposed to be returning Unit?

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
case class User (id: Integer, name: String, surname: String, address: String)
```

where member types follow the member names.

Then call `copy` directly like this,

```
val userA = User(1,"a","b","c")
userA: User(1,a,b,c)

val userA2 = a.copy(2)
userA2: User(2,a,b,c)

val userBB = a.copy(name = "bb")
userBB: User(1,bb,b,c)
```